# Typescript: Type 'Audience' is not assignable to type 'boolean'

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

The problem:

```
.filter(audience => audience)
```

I'm using VSCode and I know why it's throwing this error as it's expecting a boolean and I'm returning an object, but this is valid Javascript as I'm returning a truthy value and so a reference will be coerced to true. Can I change something in the configuration to make it work? I already made it work with:

```
.filter(audience => Boolean(audience))
```

But I'd rather avoid that.

Comment: What version of typescript are you using? With my own tests, I get no error

Comment: 2.4.2. It's actually not in the array's filter method. That's from the filter method from Observables in rxjs.

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised you are seeing this error. But if you need a boolean, truthy/falsy values are commonly converted to booleans like this:

```
.filter(audience => !!audience)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways you can do a test. As TypeScript helps you to write better code, it is picky on what it accepts (This is a good thing). Here are a few different ways to tell something that an object is a boolean.

We can cast it as an `any` (`boolean` might work too)

```
.filter(audience => <any>audience)
```

And as Frank Mentioned we can use double `!`

```
.filter(audience => !!audience)
```